# HIIT in the living room

Tags: home-exercise, hiit, interval-training, tabata

I am looking for an aerobic training system for the living room:

1. Should be possible to start with low aerobic load and gradually increase to high intensity, like HIIT or interval training.  Ideally fine-grained  control of aerobic intensity.
2. Low impact, little "noise".
3. Little equipment (by volume).  (Game consoles OK).
4. Load on muscles, joints and tendons should be low in the beginning.  This might increase gradually, like the aerobic intensity.
5. Easy to adopt according to how much time I have available.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a shopping recommendation.

Comment: Your requirements seem to have too many restrictions. I don't think there's any HIIT program that'll fit them. I think you have to be ready to get out of your comfort zone and push yourself.

Comment: @JohnP - how is this a shopping recommendation?

Answer (score 4):

Do you own a smartphone/tablet? 
If it's available then get yourself an app for Tabata/HIIT.

I personally use „Bodyweight Training by Mark Lauren“ (also available as book), which is progressive, customizeable and has a ton of exercises (and video descriptions for the iPad).
A timer for tabata and a sample HIIT workout is also built-in.

I think you get the idea...

Comment: IT seems for me Mark Lauren is focusing on strength training?

Comment: Absolutely no. Mark Lauren (and other BWE athletes) is setting his focus on coordination & functional usage.
If you set your goal for strength, you won't use your body weight. Instead you would go for (heavy) barbell training and/or powerlifting exercises (prowler, keg-lift, atlas stoning) - but that wasn't the question and would be too offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do burpees, pushups, situps, air squats, etc. with various rep schemes (e.g., 5 rounds of 10 pushups, 25 situps, 30 airsquats for time, or as many rounds as possible in 20 minutes of 20 burpees, 100 unders with a jump-rope, 15 v-ups).

Here's a great guide for no-equipment HIIT workouts: http://reebokcrossfitone.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Travel-WODs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Given you have restricted basically every parameter, I think your best bet is to get a rowing machine, stationary bike, or elliptical machine.

Comment: Thats to voluminous.  (I don't think these are impossible requirements.  I can get moderate pulse with my Wi-Fit step program.  It should be possible to get high pulse by moving more up and down, or putting the board higher)

Comment: It's the little noise restriction that is the hardest to work with. If you can tolerate the noise than jumping rope is the idea exercise. Or burpees for that matter.

Comment: Air Squats for example seems to be used in Tabata, and is "quite"